# iOS APNS Cert about to Expire (Firebase for Server Side)

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an APNS certificate that is set to expire in Jan 2017 on a live application. I have renewed the certificate and created my `.cer` and `.p12` files.

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging to handle my push notifications. If I add the new `.p12` file to the firebase console now, will that overwrite the current one and break push notifications on the live app?

If so how do I manage a seamless transition to the new certificates? Do I just wait until the new app is live in the app store and then upload the `.p12`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the New push certificate created for the same AppID and contains the bundle ID of the existing app and push certificate is only used in firebase no where else then the old versions of your app should continue receiving push notifications using the new certificate , regardless of which certificate you use

> Whenever you update your APNS certificate all version of the app that
>   had push notification will receive the notifications again. There is
>   no need to update the app for this.